# While: Break immediately after word

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, cin

I'm trying to assign some values to a vector from `cin`.
How can I achieve that the while loop breaks immediately after a specific word, e.g. `end`, was entered?
In my example it only breaks if I enter this word as "age", so only at the end of the loop. If I enter it at the beginning (as "name") it just continues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct person {
    string name;
    string age;
};
int main() {
    vector<person> myPerson;
    string text;

    while(text != "end") {
        person tempPerson;

        cout << "Name:" << endl;
        cin >> text;
        tempPerson.name = text;

        cout << "Age:" << endl;
        cin >> text;
        tempPerson.age = text;

        myPerson.push_back(tempPerson);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<myPerson.size(); i++) {
        cout << "Person No. " << i << ": " << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << myPerson[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Age: " << myPerson[i].age << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should include the `<string>` header to use `std::string`. Don't rely on indirect header includes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break` out of the loop if `"end"` is entered.

```
while (true) {
    cin >> text;
    if (text == "end")
        break;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: After every `cin`? So twice in my case? Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @user1170330 No need for that - only after the first call to `cin::operator<<`. Think about it.